# Can't initiate the google.maps.Geocoder

Tags: javascript, google-maps, undefined

I don't understand why but i'm getting this error when I try to initialize the google.maps.Geocoder.

Here is the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

And the code :

```
function updateMapPosition(map){
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); //crashes here !!
    var position = geocoder.geocode( {'address':$('#id_address').val()},
        function(results,status){
            if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
                if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map:map, position:results[0].geometry.location});
                }
                else{
                    alert("hop")
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: can you give more information on how you load the library? maybe you can post the part of the <head></head> where you load all the javascript libraries.

Answer (score 11):

Since you appear to be using something like jQuery, you may have the same issue I had where jQuery considers the script loading complete before Google Maps is actually completely "assembled". Using jQuery's [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) (equivalent to `$.ajax` with `dataType: "script"` used here), it appears parts of the maps API are not yet available in the `success`/`done` callbacks.

```
$(function() {
    var doSomethingMapRelatedInvolvingJQuery = function(geocoder, map) { ... };

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false",
        dataType: "script"
    }).done(function() {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(), // ERROR!
            activityMap = new google.maps.Map($("#map_canvas")[0], {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
                zoom: 0,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
            });

        doSomethingMapRelatedInvolvingJQuery(geocoder, map);
    });
});
```

For some reason, even though jQuery is saying the script has been executed already by executing the callbacks, parts of the Google Maps API are not yet available (possibly additional asynchronous stuff by Google after the first file executes).

The only solution I could find was to declare a global variable name to hold a function that Google Maps would be responsible for calling when it was completely ready. You can give it that control by adding the `callback={yourfunctionname}` querystring parameter to the URL (e.g., `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=googleMapsCallback&sensor=false`). It's not the prettiest solution, but it works.

```
var googleMapsCallback;
$(function() {
    var doSomethingMapRelatedInvolvingJQuery= function(geocoder, map) { ... };

    googleMapsCallback = function() {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(), // Works when google makes the call.
            activityMap = new google.maps.Map($("#map_canvas")[0], {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
                zoom: 0,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
            });

        doSomethingMapRelatedInvolvingJQuery(geocoder, map);
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=googleMapsCallback&sensor=false",
        dataType: "script"
    });
});
```

#### EDIT:

I put together a [proof-of-concept jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patridge/SLAPy/) that pulls all that ugliness into a jQuery-extended method that allows for Deferred-chaining. Here's a quick example of how it can be used:

```
$.loadGoogleMaps().done(function () {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    // ... do stuff with your geocoder here ...
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use the Google AJAX API Loader to load the Google Maps API you must explicitly specify whether your app uses a sensor, otherwise you won't get the Geocoder object.

```
google.load('maps','3.6',{other_params:'sensor=false'});
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me like `Geocoder` isn't defined, hence the error that `Undefined is not a function`.  However, `google.maps` is defined or you would have gotten an error that it wasn't defined before `Geocoder` was resolved.

You'll need to check how you're loading the Map API because it doesn't seem to have been loaded correctly.

Comment: I am having the same issue and it is, as you say, because Geocoder() function is not defined. Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805614/google-maps-geocoder-getting-null-in-cordova-2-6.. struck with this issues

Comment: I had this issue with v3 maps api. Make your variable declaration global -- "var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();". Declare it outside of your function and you'll be all good. "var geocoder; function updateMapPosition() { geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();...}. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, it was because of a bad href url in the script tag for the Maps library:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.6&sensor=false&key=XXXX" ....
```