# Loading Google charts and angular using require not working

Tags: google-visualization, require

I am trying to load google visualization (charts) using Require.js along with angular js and Jquery

I refered to many posts and from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795648/how-to-load-google-maps-api-with-requirejs) I saw we could use the https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins/blob/master/src/goog.js plugin

Here is my code. But this is not working, it is not loading any subsequent scripts.

```
require.config({    
    paths: {
    async: 'lib/async',
        goog: 'lib/goog',
        propertyParser : 'lib/propertyParser',
    jquery: 'lib/jquery.min',
    'jquery.ui.widget': 'lib/jquery.ui.widget',
        jqfileupload: 'lib/jquery.fileupload',
    jqfileuploadiframe: 'lib/jquery.iframe-transport',
    angular:'lib/angular.min',
    ngUi:'lib/angular-ui.min',
    ngResource:'lib/angular-resource.min',
    ngCookies:'lib/angular-cookies.min',
    bootstrap:'lib/bootstrap.min'
    },
    shim: { 
    'angular' : {exports:'angular',deps:['jquery']},
    'ngResource' : {exports:'ngResource',deps:['angular']},
    'ngUi' : {exports:'ngUi',deps:['angular']},
    'ngCookies' : {exports:'ngCookies',deps:['angular']},
    'jquery.ui.widget' : ['jquery'],
    'jqfileupload' : ['jquery','jqfileuploadiframe','jquery.ui.widget'],    
    'bootstrap' : ['jquery'],   
    }
});

define(['angular','jquery','ngResource','ngCookies','ngUi','bootstrap','jqfileupload','goog!visualization,1,packages:[corechart]'],function(){

var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

});
```

It gives me the error

```
Error: No module: myApp
```

If I remove the `'goog!visualization,1,packages:[corechart]'` entry, it all works fine

Please help and thanks in advance