# Load async resource with requirejs timeout

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I tried to load the Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript with requirejs and the async plugin:

```js
require.config({
    paths : {
        async : '../lib/requirejs/async'
    },
    waitSeconds: 60
});

define('gapi', ['async!https://apis.google.com/js/client.js!callback'],
    function(){
        console.log('gapi loaded');
        return gapi.client;
    }
);

require(['gapi'], function(){
    console.log("Callback");
    console.log(gapi);
});
```

The usual way to [load this library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js) is

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
```

Everything is loaded in less than 2s but I always get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: async!https://apis.google.com/js/client.js!callback_unnormalized2,async!https://apis.google.com/js/client.js!callback
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout
```

Comment: Please where you able to get this working after optimization with r.js (requirejs optimizer)?, For me it works normally but after optimization it doesn't .

Comment: ^^ Did you manage to fix it after optimization?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR;** change the `!callback` to `!onload` that should fix the timeout.

```
define('gapi', ['async!https://apis.google.com/js/client.js!onload'],
    function(){
        console.log('gapi loaded');
        return gapi.client;
    }
);
```

The value after the `!` is used as the argument name for the async callback, in this case the URI loaded will be something like `https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=__async_req_3__` where `__async_req_3__` is a global variable (callback function) triggered as soon as the Google API is loaded (notifies the plugin that all dependencies are met).

Comment: You'll likely need to return just `gapi`, as opposed to `gapi.client`

Comment: I have tried this and it works if i have not done my build with grunt , but once i build with grunt , it marks the gapi object as undefined .