# requirejs and async timeout error

Tags: requirejs

I've referenced the solution here but it doesn't seem to work for me no matter what I do the script just doesn't load:
[Load async resource with requirejs timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067650/load-async-resource-with-requirejs-timeout)

This is what I have:

```
(function () {
    require.config({
        paths: {
        async: '/dist/async',
     }
});
require(["gapiModule"], function (gapiModule) {

);
})();

// gapiModule
define(['async!https://apis.google.com/js/client.js!onload'], function () {
    console.log('google client added');
   }
);
```

No matter what I try I get a script timeout error, any ideas?
Thanks very much

Comment: False alarm...seems there was a problem at google's end, all of a sudden overnight the code started working as if by magic....

Comment: then please close your question