# RequireJs Google maps google is not define

Tags: google-maps-api-3, requirejs

I have a simple nodejs project that should load asynchronously the google maps api javascript, i followed this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15796543
and my app.js is like this:

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    bodyParser  = require("body-parser"),
    methodOverride = require("method-override");
    https = require("https");
    requirejs = require('requirejs');

requirejs.config({
    waitSeconds : 500,
    isBuild: true,
    paths : {
        'async': 'node_modules/requirejs-plugins/src/async',
    }
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send("Hello World!");
});

requirejs(["async!http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&sensor=false"], function() {
    console.log(google);
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("asd");
});
```

package.json:

```
{
 "name": "rest-google-maps-api",
 "version": "2.0.0",
 "dependencies": {
     "express": "^4.7.1",
     "method-override": "^2.1.2",
     "body-parser": "^1.5.1",
     "requirejs": "2.3.3",
     "requirejs-plugins": "1.0.2"
 }
}
```

i've got always the same error:

**ReferenceError: google is not defined**

Comment: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&sensor=false

Did you actually put your key in the url?

Comment: yes, it's the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that you are trying to run in Node code that is really meant to be used in a browser.

#### The `async` plugin

This plugin needs to be able to add `script` elements to `document` and needs `window`. I see you set `isBuild: true` in your RequireJS configuration. It does silence the error that `async` immediately raises if you do not use this flag, but this is not a solution because:

- `isBuild` is really meant to be set internally by RequireJS's optimizer (or any optimizer that is compatible with RequireJS), not manually like you are doing.
- `isBuild` means to indicate to plugins that they are running as part of an optimization run. However, your code is using the plugin at run time rather than as part of an optimization. So setting `isBuild: true` is a lie and will result in undesirable behavior. The async plugin is written in such a way that it effectively does nothing if `isBuild` is true. Other plugins may crash.

#### Google's Map API

It also expects a browser environment. The very first line I see when I download its code is this:

```
window.google = window.google || {};
```

Later in the code there are references to `window.document` and `window.postMessage`.

I don't know if it is possible to run the code you've been trying to load from Google in Node. I suspect you'd most likely need something like [`jsdom`](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) to provide a browser-like environment to the API.

Comment: i tried to use this api without a browser, on a rest api, but i couldnt find a solution, i also tried with jsdom and didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

assuming you did everything else correctly, which I am not testing here. The reason you are getting the error is because you call console.log(google) and there is no google variable. You need to pass google in as a reference in your call back function. This will either get rid of the error, or change the error if you have set up requirejs incorrectly.

```
requirejs(["async!http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&sensor=false"], 
function( **google** ) {
    console.log(google);
});
```

see the requirejs docs http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html#1

Comment: thats the problem, anything i put there doesnt work, can you give an example?, thanks