# google.maps.Geocoder() getting null in cordova 2.6

Tags: android, cordova, google-geocoder

I'm using geocoder in my phonegap project. This is working fine in when im using cordova 1.7 but when I changed the cordova version to 2.6, it is returning undefined..

Any idea what am I missing?

`var geocode= new google.maps.Geocoder()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `var geocode = new google.maps.Geocoder();`

When creating any object of class (of course Javascript has only objects), use new to instantiate.