# create marker with geocode in function JS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So, i am trying to create a marker on my google map. In my page html/jsp i have the code of the map where i call a function js : createOfficiel(address, map);
In this function i tried to geocode the string address and create a marker thanks to the geocode. But it doesn't seem to work, can you tell me why ?
Thank you :)

Here is my function .js :

```
function createOfficiel (address, map){
var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
var officiel = 'images/officiel.png'; 
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.geocode({"address": address}, 
        function(results) {
               var marqueurOfficiel = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: results[0].geometry.location,
               map: map,
               icon: officiel,
               optimized: false
               });
        });

   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398342/cant-initiate-the-google-maps-geocoder

Comment: [Your code works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/mn8w9phe/).  Do you have an input element with id="address" on your page?  The "address" parameter to the function as written doesn't do anything.

Comment: i just put the answer below, thanks

Answer (score -1):

well i just find it, the main problem _ i think _ was the position value of the marker. I splited the position in lat + lng.

So here is the code working :

```
function createOfficiel (address, map){
var officiel = 'images/officiel.png'; 
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    if (geocoder) {
           geocoder.geocode({
           "address": address}, 
           function(results) {
                var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                var marqueurOfficiel = new google.maps.Marker({
                     position: {
                             lat: lat, 
                             lng: lng
                     },
                     map: map,
                     icon: officiel,
                     optimized: false
                });
         });

}
```

}