# AngularJS test controller with google maps in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I showing a map using the NgMap directive with this controller:

```
app.controller('AddStoreController', function ($scope, StoresService, NgMap, appConfig) {

    StoresService.getCompanies().then(function(data){
        $scope.companies = data.data;
    });
    $scope.store = {};
    $scope.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    $scope.addStore = function () {
        StoresService.addStore($scope.store).then(function () {
            $scope.store = {};
            $scope.addStoreForm.$setPristine();
        });
    };

    $scope.gmapsKey = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='+appConfig.gmapsKey;
    $scope.markerPosition = 'current-location';
    NgMap.getMap().then(function (map) {
        $scope.map = map;
    });
    $scope.placeMarker = function (e) {
        var position = e.latLng;
        $scope.markerPosition = [position.lat(),position.lng()];
        $scope.store.lat = position.lat();
        $scope.store.long = position.lng();
        $scope.getAddress();
        $scope.mapDirty = true;
    };
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(location) {
        $scope.markerPosition = [location.coords.latitude,location.coords.longitude];
        $scope.store.lat = location.coords.latitude;
        $scope.store.long = location.coords.longitude;
        $scope.getAddress();
    }, function(error){
        alert('you should enable gelocation');
    });
    $scope.getAddress = function(){
        var latlng = {lat : parseFloat($scope.store.lat), lng : parseFloat($scope.store.long)}
        $scope.geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                $scope.store.address = results[0].address_components[1].long_name+' '+results[0].address_components[0].long_name;
                $scope.store.city = results[0].address_components[2].long_name;
                $scope.store.province = results[0].address_components[3].long_name;
                $scope.store.country = results[0].address_components[5].long_name;
                $scope.store.zip = results[0].address_components[6].long_name;
            }
        });
    }


});
```

and my test

```
describe("Stores Controller", function () {
beforeEach(function () {
    module('storesController');
});
beforeEach(function () {
        var StoresService, createController, scope, rootScope, $q;
        // Provide will help us create fake implementations for our dependencies
        module(function ($provide) {

            $provide.value('StoresService', {
                getStores: function () {
                    return {
                        then: function (callback) {
                            return callback({data: {name: 'store1'}});
                        }
                    };
                },
                deleteStore: function () {
                    return {
                        then: function (callback) {
                            return callback({data: {name: 'store1'}});
                        }
                    };
                },
                getCompanies: function () {
                    return {
                        then: function (callback) {
                            return callback({data: {name: 'store1'}});
                        }
                    };
                }
            });

            return null;
        });
    });

describe('AddStoreController', function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
        var NgMap, appConfig;
         module(function ($provide) {
            $provide.value('NgMap');
            $provide.value('appConfig');
            return null;
         });
    });
    beforeEach(function(){
        inject(function ($controller, _$rootScope_, _StoresService_,_NgMap_,_appConfig_) {
            rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
            NgMap = _NgMap_;
            appConfig = _appConfig_;
            StoresService = _StoresService_;
            createController = function () {
                return $controller("AddStoreController", {
                    $scope: scope,
                });
            };
        });
    });
    it('should call getCompanies', function(){
         spyOn(StoresService, 'getCompanies').and.callThrough();
        createController();
        expect(StoresService.getCompanies).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
});
```

});

And I'm getting this error ReferenceError: google is not defined, on the line $scope.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder
How can I make it work?

Comment: Please see this post....apparently you have to explicitly state whether your application is using a sensor or not.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398342/cant-initiate-the-google-maps-geocoder

Comment: The controller is working correctly, I'm just trying to run a working test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, first I all I forgot to include the library in the karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    basePath: './',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
        'public/js/libs/angular.min.js',
        'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js',
        'public/js/**/*.js',
        'test/**/*.js'
    ],
[...]
```

and the just some changes on my test

```
[...]
describe('AddStoreController', function(){
        beforeEach(function(){
            var NgMap, appConfig;
             module(function ($provide) {
                $provide.value('NgMap',{
                    getMap: function () {
                        return {
                            then: function () {

                            }
                        };
                    }
                });
                $provide.value('appConfig',{
                    gmapsKey : 'asdasd'
                });
                return null;
             });
        });
        beforeEach(function(){
            inject(function ($controller, _$rootScope_, _StoresService_,_NgMap_,_appConfig_) {
                rootScope = _$rootScope_;
                scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
                NgMap = _NgMap_;
                appConfig = _appConfig_;
                StoresService = _StoresService_;
                createController = function () {
                    return $controller("AddStoreController", {
                        $scope: scope, 
                    });
                };
            });
        });
        it('should call getCompanies', function(){
             spyOn(StoresService, 'getCompanies').and.callThrough();
            createController();

            expect(StoresService.getCompanies).toHaveBeenCalled();
        })
    });
```

Comment: Great, that you found a solution! :-) To make it easier for others to see that your problem was solved, you can mark your answer as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the parenthesis

$scope.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();